# Adding listener to Ext.grid.ColumnModel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

i was trying to add a listener(columnshow) to Ext.grid.ColumnModel inside a Ext.grid.GridPanel, but my listener function is not being called.

pls help.

parts of code pasted below.

```
    var gridCm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
       columns  : data.result.columns,
       listeners    : {
            columnshow  : function( a , b ) {
                alert(1);   
            }   
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not supported? There is no `columnshow` in Ext 3.4

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.ColumnModel

columnshow is available in ExtJS 4.0+.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-event-columnshow